# What is the fastest way I can read and process this one line file in Java?

Tags: java, performance, io

I have the following code:

```java
static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> parseInput(String filename) throws IOException {
        String[] edges = new String[0];

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            edges = line.split(",");
        }

        br.close();

        edges[0] = edges[0].replace("[", "");
        edges[edges.length - 1] = edges[edges.length - 1].replace("]", "");

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < edges.length) {
            Integer l = Integer.parseInt(edges[i].replace("(", ""));
            Integer r = Integer.parseInt(edges[i + 1].replace(")", ""));
            if(adj.get(l) == null) {
                adj.put(l, new ArrayList<Integer>());
                adj.get(l).add(r);
            }
            else {
                adj.get(l).add(r);
            }
            i += 2;
        }
        return adj;
    }
```

It reads a text file which looks similar to this: `[(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(3,5),(4,5)]` which represents the list of edges in a graph. It has only one line. The program reads the list and adds the edges in a HashMap which represents Adjacency List.

What would be the fastest way to read that file and extract the edges to the HashMap?

Comment: It doesn't matter, surely? Reading one line of text however long surely isn't going to dominate your runtime? Your existing code is OK but I would avoid `String.split()`. I would probably use a `java.util.Scanner` for this.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Use a profiler on your application and find out where it spends the majority of its time. Although it's just guesswork, I'd bet its opening the file, or maybe the `line.split(",")`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that streams and regex in general are slower but have the advantage of being more compact and readable. So even if my answer doesn't answer your question about best performance in terms of time, it might be worth considering if you only have one line to read and your method is not called so often in succession:

```
static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> parseInput(String filename) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(filename);
    String line = Files.readAllLines(path).get(0);
    return Pattern.compile("\\d+,\\d+")
            .matcher(line)
            .results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .map(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                            Integer.parseInt(i.split(",")[0]),
                            Integer.parseInt(i.split(",")[1])))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it is interesting. However, time is very crucial in this case

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
if (readChar())!='[') {
   throw new SyntaxError("must start with '['");
}
for (;;) {
  switch(readChar()) {
     case ']': break;
     case '(': readPair(); break;
     case ',': break;
     default: 
        throw new SyntaxError();
  }
}

void readPair() {
    int key=readNumber();
    if (readChar())!=',') {
          throw new SyntaxError();
    }
    int value=readNumber();
    hashmap.put(key, value);
    if (readChar())!=')') {
          throw new SyntaxError();
    }
}
```

Some important details are omitted, for complete description, search "recursive descent parser".

Comment: Recursive descent parsing has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne why do you think so? It solves the problem in a performant way, whithout creating multiple objects which is a side effect of `replace()`.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I wrote it and for some reason it was slower. Maybe it is a problem with my implementation. Doesn't it take more to read a character by character in Java in general, rather than reading into the buffer?

Comment: @Ivalin why did not you publish your solution?